# Parse and get specific results from string?

Tags: xstring, l3regex

I have the following strings: `lec-01.tex`, `lec-02.tex`, ..., `lec-10.tex`, `lec-11.tex`, ... How can I parse these strings and get only the digits? Like, for the string `lec-01.tex`, how can I get only `1` and for `lec-11.tex`, how can I get only `11`?

Comment: How do you "source lec-02.tex"? Wouldn't you have `\figfolder\lecprefix\lecnum\lecextension` and `\lecfolder\lecprefix\lecnum\lecextension` with `\lecnum` as the "source"?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of  [Pulling numbers out of a file name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464025)  and [Read metadata from a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661906)